# INSERT into New Table after getting generated through SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables for customers. In the Customer X table when we add a row with customer details and a particular ID is generated. I want to insert that ID in the Customer Y table ( Customer Y has the same customer name as in the Customer X table, but ID is missing).

I am executing the query in the Spring boot application.

Extracting sec ID from Customer X table after it is generated:

````
@Query(
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER X(CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_TYPE,CUSTOMER_ADDRESS, CUSTOMER_ STATUS) VALUES (A, B, C, D) RETURNING SEC_ID));
Integer returnSecId (@Param String A, @Param String B, @Param String C, @Param String D);```

Updating into Customer Y table:

```@Query
(UPDATE CUSTOMER Y SET SEC_ID = ?1)
void updateSecId (@Param Integer newSecId)```

To get SEC_ID:

```Integer newSecID = customerdataX.returnSecID (A,B,C,D);
customerdataY.updateSecId( newSecId);```

Error: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException
````

Comment: Use AFTER INSERT trigger.

Comment: I didnt get you. I am able to get SEC_ID.

Comment: Have you checked the exception in details you must get something like  `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ` which shall help to trouble shoot further